# Python library for Geographically Weighted Regression (GWD)

Tags: python, software-recommendations, regression, library

The user @GrantD71 [seems to have implemented a GWD in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86341/what-are-the-most-efficient-geographic-weighted-regression-packages) through hard-coding using Numpy/Scipy. He asked for library/package to perform GWD but the best reply was given using an R package. I'm looking for a python library for GWD.

I looked in [Scipy Docs](https://www.scipy.org) and (almost) exhaustively googled it with no success. I found [pygwr](https://github.com/mkordi/pygwr), but not sure if it's a completely developed and tested project. I even figured out how to install it and used it.

Does exists a wide-spread python library used for GWR? What is the most beneficial way (without the need of hard-coding) to perform it in python?

Comment: pygwr seems to be the standard in my cursory google search, you could always try pygwr and then implement it in another program to check the results...

Comment: @GrantD71, have you found such a library?

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution implemented in Python. I did not try; however, there are well-documented notebooks with examples. Let me know if they work.

https://github.com/TaylorOshan/gwr